# Visualizing MySQL data using D3js and JSON format in Django

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

This is my first post here so please ignore any naive errors please.

I have successfully retrieved my data from database in JSON format. The database has several fields of which I require only timestamp and value. Now, I tried using **.values("timestamp", "readings")** but on serialization it popped an error as - no attribute _meta. Had to resort to **.only("timestamp", "readings")** but it returned all the attributes.

Can you please tell me how to go about filtering the attributes and also visualizing it using D3js or any other library.

Some relevant details - 
Model -

```
**class Readings(models.Model):
    meter_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    readings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places= 10, default=Decimal('0.0000'))**
```

The result returned is of the form -

**[{"model": "log.readings", "pk": 4093, "fields": {"meter_id": "c30d4d9a-48b7-56fa-b714-c36247ee7aa8", "timestamp": "2017-04-01T00:00:00Z", "readings": "0E-10"}}**

From this I only need the timestamp and readings field

Views.py -

```
def current(request):
    user = Details.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    data = Readings.objects.filter(meter_id=user[0].meter_id).only('timestamp', 'readings')
    temp = serializers.serialize('json', data)
    return render_to_response("current.html", {'for_graph': temp})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself. The JSON was parsed correctly so the attributes could be differentiated at runtime using Javascript. Also charts.js is a great library to plot different graphs using JSON objects :)